# Android: how to measure whether textview having enough space to render textview content

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Please find layout

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="12345678901234567890"/>


<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="12345678901234567890"/>


<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="12345678901234567890"/>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

What I want is to move textview at textview or add new textview at runtime? but more importantly how I can measure whether textview have enough space in right side to render my content.

Answer (score 0):

```
titleTxt.post {
    val lineCount = titleTxt.lineCount
    if (lineCount > 1) {
        // Already break in 2 lines, update the content
        // Do whatever you want with your content here
        val textBuilder = StringBuilder()
        for (line in 0 until lineCount) {
            val layout = titleTxt.layout
            textBuilder.append(titleTxt.text.subSequence(layout.getLineStart(line), layout.getLineEnd(line)))
                    .append("\n")
        }

        titleTxt.text = textBuilder

        // Here I lower my font size so the overall height is not too big
        titleTxt.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.font_large).toFloat())
    }
}
```

Here is what I do in my project:

- I check the line count
- If it's more than 2 then it doesn't have enough space in 1 line for your content. 
  Use the `layout` instance to get the substring of any line you want. Do whatever you want with your content

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your wrapper layou is a LinearLayout, you may use this code to make sure whether have enought space in horizontal:

```
wrapperLayout.post{
        if(wrapperLayout.width > textView1.width + textView2.width + textView3.width) {
            //the space is enougth to contain three textview
        } else {
            //the sapce is not enougth
        }
    }
```